# How to generate kedro pipelines automatically (like DataEngineerOne does)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grid-search, kedro, data-pipeline

Having seen the video of DataEngineerOne: [How To Use a Parameter Range to Generate Pipelines Automatically](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eRBNra6TVo) I want to automate a pipeline that simulates an electronic circuit. I want to do a grid search over multiple central frequencies of a bandpass filter, and for each one run the `simulate` pipeline.

In the pipeline registry, the grid search parameters are passed to the `create_pipeline()` function's `kwargs`.

```py
# pipeline_registry.py
"""Project pipelines."""
from typing import Dict

from kedro.pipeline import Pipeline, pipeline
from kedro.config import ConfigLoader

from my_project.pipelines import grid_search as grd


def register_pipelines() -> Dict[str, Pipeline]:
    """Register the project's pipelines.

    Returns:
        A mapping from a pipeline name to a ``Pipeline`` object.
    """

    conf_path = r'C:\Users\user\python_projects\my_project\conf'
    conf_loader = ConfigLoader(conf_source=conf_path, env="local")
    gs_params = conf_loader.get('**/grid_search.yml')

    gridsearch_pipeline = grd.create_pipeline(**gs_params['grid_search'])

    return {
        "__default__":gridsearch_pipeline,
        "grd"  : gridsearch_pipeline,
    }
```

In the pipeline's `pipeline.py` file, I loop over the grid search params, and in each loop create a new pipeline with its own namespace.

```py
# grid_search\pipeline.py

from kedro.pipeline import Pipeline, node, pipeline
from my_project.pipelines.grid_search.nodes import grid_search
from numpy import arange

def create_pipeline(**kwargs) -> Pipeline:

    fmin = kwargs['f_central_min']
    fmax = kwargs['f_central_max']
    fstp = kwargs['f_central_step']
    cfs = arange(fmin, fmax, fstp) # central frequencies

    for cf in cfs:
        def generate_freq_node(cf):
            def generated():
                return cf
            return generated

        pipeline_key = f'pipeline_{cf}'

        pipe_gridsearch = Pipeline([
            node(
                 func=generate_freq_node(cf),
                 inputs=None,
                 outputs=pipeline_key,
            ),
            node(
                 func=grid_search,
                 inputs=["msmts_table", "params:grid_search"],
                 outputs=None,
                 name="node_grid_search",
                ),
        ])

        pipe_complete = pipeline(
            pipe=pipe_gridsearch,
            inputs={"msmts_table": "msmts_table"},
            parameters={"params:grid_search": pipeline_key},
            namespace=pipeline_key,

        )

    return pipe_complete
```

In the `grid_search.yml` file:

```yaml
grid_search:
  f_central_min : 100000
  f_central_max : 500000
  f_central_step: 100000
```

And finally the `grid_search\nodes.py`:

```py
from typing import Dict, Any
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import arange


def grid_search(msmts_table: DataFrame,
                grd_params: Dict[str, Any],
                ) -> DataFrame:
    """Repeatedly run the simulation pipeline for all the parameters passed in params."""

    print(grd_params)
```

When I now `kedro run --pipeline grd`, I get the following error:

```py
ValueError: Pipeline input(s) {'params:pipeline_400000'} not found in the DataCatalog
```

This is actually something I would expect, as the datasets are not specified in the `catalog.yml`. However, in the above mentioned video, this approach works, and DataEngineerOne says that the params `pipeline_key` are saved as memroy dataset. Is this something that changed in a never version of kedro, or what am I missing here?
Do I have to specify all the parameters as separate datasets in the catalog? This would somehow destroy the whole point of this automation...

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a solution in the meantime, otherwise I suggest you to try the following modifications in the last section of your `pipeline.py` code:

1. `pipe_complete += pipeline(`
   instead of
   `pipe_complete = pipeline(`
   to add the pipeline in the loop
2. `parameters={"grid_search": pipeline_key},`
   instead of
   `parameters={"params:grid_search": pipeline_key},`